# ExpandableListView null object Reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView` in my `Fragment` that shows some data. I call the `Fragment` when i press an icon.

```
public void searchClick(){
        Fragment frag = new Results();

        FragmentTransaction ft  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.FragFaecher,frag).commit();



        displayList();


    }
```

`displayList()` then should populate the List and show it

```
public void displayList(){
        populateList();

        expList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expList);
        listAdapter = new ExpListAdapter(MainActivity.this,parentList);
        expList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
```

In FragmentClass the Layout with the `ExpandableListView` is inflated within the `fragment_results` Layout

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }
```

**fragment layout:**

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/results"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="?android:colorBackground"
        android:clickable="true">


       <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:colorBackground"
            android:childDivider="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/expList" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I suppose the problem is, that the `displayList()` method tries to find a `View` that is not yet created. I tried to return a boolean when the `View` was created, but that did not work. Is there any other possible way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: please share the layout file for the Fragment

Comment: sorry I could not help you. Then I think your best option is to call the activity in the fragment's onStart()  to notify it that the Views are accessible now. That is, if you are able to write code for the fragment.

Comment: anyways, thank you for your effort.